# How to undo (or can you) a review vote

Tags: support, voting

I accidentally cast a reopen vote - is there a mechanism to undo that? I could not find one. I suppose the (expected) lack of consenting votes will accomplish same.

Comment: I don't recall a mechanism for that but I am not sure.  If I were you I would simply comment that the reopen vote was an error so that reviewers are not left to wonder what they are missing.

Comment: It is strange that one can retract a close vote, but not a reopen vote. I see this as a flaw in the site design.